# How to show Total Least Error is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Total Least Error:

$\phi(t)=a_0+a_1t^1+...+a_Kt^K$

best approximates the data as $(t_1,\phi_1),...,(t_N,\phi(t_N))$

I would like to show that : $\sum_{j=1}^N |\phi_j-\phi(t_j)|$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Attempt:

define $f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^N |\phi_j-\phi(t_j)|$ , $f:\mathbb{R^n}->\mathbb{R}$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sum_{j=1}^N |\phi_j-\phi(x_j)|-\sum_{i=1}^N |\phi_i-\phi(y_i)||\le |\sum_{j=1}^N \phi_j-\phi(x_j) -\sum_{i=1}^N \phi_i+\phi(y_i)|\le|\phi(y_1)-\phi(x_1)|+|\phi(y_2)-\phi(x_2)|+...+|\phi(y_N)-\phi(x_N)|\le C||x-y||_1$

At the last inequality, I assumed that $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous. This was the only way I could think of. I am not sure whether $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous is given.(I know it must be continuous)

Comment: I think the arguments of $f$ should not be the sampling points $t_j$ but the sampling values $\phi_j$. Note that two sets of sampling values will give two different approximation polynomials. -- In what norm is the approximation the best, i.e., which minimization problem is solved by $\phi(t)$?

Comment: the minimization is over $\sum_{j=1}^N |\phi_j-\phi(t_j)|$.so norm $L_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you get for the distance function $d_C(x)=\inf_{v\in C} d(x,v)$ via the triangle inequality
$$
d_C(y)\le d(y,w)\le d(x,y)+d(x,w)
$$
and taking the infimum of all $w\in C$
$$
d_C(y)\le d(x,y)+d_C(x)
$$
and vice versa, so that
$$
|d_C(y)-d_C(x)|\le d(x,y)
$$
proving the Lipschitz continuity in this general setting.

---

In your case, $C$ is the set of $N$-tuples of points $(p(t_1),…,p(t_N))$ generated by polynomials $p$ of degree at most $K$. The question is non-trivial only for $K\le N$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it is non-trivial for $K\le N$

Comment: Because for $K>N$ you get the full space, thus the distance is always zero. Only for $K\le N$ you get a proper sub-space.